# General Solution of First Order ODE

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

so the problem at hand is:

$(2x-3)\frac{dx}{dt}+t-2=0$

and the solution is

$x(t)=\frac{3}{2}\frac{\sqrt{C-2t(t-4)+9}}{2}$

>

Originally. I tried the exactness test but found that both $\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}$ equalled zero... so I tried another route and made some progress... I rearranged the equation so that:

$(2x-3)dx=-(t-2)dt$

$\int{(2x-3)dx}=-\int{(t-2)dt}$

$x^{2}-3x=-\frac{t^{2}}{2}+2t+C$

>

now, using the solution as a guide, I got my solution so far to:

$2x^{2}-6x=-t(t-4)+D$

This looks abit more promising, but I still get stuck... I figured that this isnt just a problem with algebraic manipulation, I'm actually missing something here or doing something wrong... Any ideas??

Comment: You're almost there. We want x in terms of t; if we move the entire right hand side of that equation to the left such that the entire thing equals zero, what formula can we use such that we would gain an equation for x that would only be in terms of the coefficients of the left hand side?

Comment: I was thinking a quadratic, but I couldnt visualise how it would work... is that how it's done??

Comment: After you move the right hand side over to the left, treat it as a giant $C$ constant. Then you can treat is a quadratic. Once done, back-substitute in and you should have your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^{2}-3x=-\frac{t^{2}}{2}+2t+C\\(x-3/2)^2-\frac94=-\frac{t^2}2+2t+C\\x=\frac32\pm\sqrt{\frac{-t^2+4t+C}{2}}\\x=\frac32\pm\frac{\sqrt{C-2t(t-4)+9}}2$$
At some steps, I changed the integration constant a little bit, this doesn't make any difference since the constant is arbitrary anyway.

Also, this slightly disagrees with what you give as the solution. I guess your question must have a typo?

Comment: this is all correct, thanks! although I dont see the point in having a C + 9, couldnt it just be lumped together as a new constant D?? oh well.. this is what the teacher shows so I'll roll with it.. thankyou again mate

Comment: @GeorgeDimitriou yes it could be lumped together haha. Strangely enough, Wolfram Alpha also gives the additional $9$. I guess it must arise from a different method being used to solve the equation.